# intercept Calendar task,meetings

Tags: android, calendar

is there any way to intercept calendar task,meetings.
Means track task and meeting on insert,edit and update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

till now gdata not supported on android.
http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/

no g data libraries available.

Answer (score 1):

Not through the SDK, sorry.